# Get list of artifacts / packages from azure-devops-extension-api

Tags: azure-devops-extensions

It's really hard to find examples on using the azure-devops-extension-api & SDK.

I'm developing a Azure Devops Extension Hub using react and typescript and using [azure-devops-extension-api](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-extension-api) with their [SDK](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-extension-sdk)

I wan't to be able to get a list of packages by a feed in Azure Devops.

[image]

It looks like I need get a list of [feeds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/artifacts/feed%20%20management/get%20feeds?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0)

Then query [get packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/artifacts/artifact%20%20details/get%20packages?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0)

But i'm really not sure how to do this. It doesn't look like it's implemented in either of the two API's so i guess i need to fetch them myself. I have tried using plain [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch), but looks like that's not the way to go.

I have seen something called [WebApi](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/azure-devops-extension-api/restclientrequestparams?view=azdevops-ext-latest) but i'm not sure how to use it so i hope anyone in here have an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, until now, we does not provide any SDK and class can let you get packages info from Feed directly. But there has a work around can for you consider: use Service Endpoint.

The logic of this work around is create a service connection with your Feed URL.

Step1: Get the Feed Url:

[image]

Step2: Create a service connection by select **Generic**.

[image]

This method is actually creating a bridge to connect the **Client** and the **Feed** by using **service endpoint**.

At this time, you could access this Feed service connection by using [ServiceEndpoint Rest Client API](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-extension-api/tree/master/src/ServiceEndpoint). You can check this [sample](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-extension-api/issues/12#issuecomment-480492476).

Comment: Ahh clever! Why didn't i think of that! Thank you :)